# Avoiding Javascript Memory Leaks from the Creation of Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, memory-leaks

I have some `HTML` and `Javascript` code that draws a 2D `canvas` in the page. In the task manager, I can see memory increasing rapidly until the web page freezes.

Please let me know how I can prevent memory leaks or provide me with some alternative code that is able to draw `canvas` on the browser without creating such leaks.

```js
function setup() {
  // insert setup code here
}

function draw() {
    // insert drawing code here
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    canvas.id     = "CursorLayer";
    canvas.width  = 1224;
    canvas.height = 600;
    canvas.style.zIndex   = 8;
    canvas.style.position = "absolute";
    canvas.style.border   = "1px solid";

    document.body.appendChild(canvas);
 
    var c2 = canvas.getContext('2d');
 
    var centerX=canvas.width/2-100;
    var centerY=canvas.height/2-100;
 
    c2.fillStyle = '#696969';
    c2.beginPath();
    c2.moveTo(centerX, centerY);
    c2.lineTo(centerX+200,centerY);
    c2.lineTo(centerX+200, centerY+200);
    c2.lineTo(centerX, centerY+200);
    c2.closePath();
    c2.fill();

    // adding source location

    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.fillStyle = '#008000';

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc( 20, canvas.height-20, 10, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();

    // adding destination location
   
    var ctx1 = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx1.fillStyle = '#f00';

    ctx1.beginPath();
    ctx1.arc( canvas.width-20, 20, 10, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx1.stroke();
    ctx1.closePath();
    ctx1.fill();
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
 <title>Robot Path Planning</title>
            <style>
         body {
      padding: 0;
                    margin: 0;
  }
     </style>
     <script src="../p5.min.js"></script>
     <script src="../addons/p5.dom.min.js"></script>
     <script src="../addons/p5.sound.min.js"></script>
     <script src="sketch.js"></script>
        </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

[Browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y3WVB.png) 
[Memory consumption](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XG08q.png)

Comment: There is nothing in the code to show a memory leak. Memory leaks are very rare, the likely cause of excessive memory consumption is your code allocating too much memory such as creating too many canvases. I would ask how often is the `draw` function called as it creates a new canvas. If draw is called many times (as maybe part of an animation) you should create the canvas once outside the draw function, not inside it.

Comment: Your script is a p5 sketch. Why do you even use the Context2d methods? Use p5 syntax instead. https://p5js.org/get-started/#sketch

Answer (score 3):

Apparently your code is creating a new `canvas` entity for each `draw` call and this doesn't make sense.

You should instead create the canvas **only once** and then just do drawing on it in the `draw` call. If you need to clear the previous frame you can just reset the `width`/`height` properties or call `clearRect`.